# Tensorflow: creating a matrix with variables as elements

Tags: python, tensorflow

In Tensorflow, I'm trying to create the following matrix:

```
A = [[a, 0], [0,b]]
```

Where `a` and `b` are the parameters I'm trying to solve for.

Here's what I have so far:

```
a =  tf.Variable((1,), name="a", dtype = tf.float64)
b = tf.Variable((1,), name="b", dtype = tf.float64)
const = tf.constant(0,dtype = tf.float64, shape = (1,))
A0 = tf.transpose(tf.stack([a,const]))
A1 = tf.transpose(tf.stack([const,b]))
A = tf.stack([A0,A1])
```

However the shape of A ends up being (2,1,2) which is wrong (since A0 and B0 both have shapes (1,2))

**Is there an easier way to create the matrix object A in Tensorflow, or does anyone know why the shape is getting messed up with what I'm doing?**

Comment: Would it be easier to make `A` a variable and solve for `a[0,0]` and `A[1,1]` instead?

Comment: Thought about that, but what I wrote is actually the simplified version where a actually = (1-delta)/alpha and b = delta (e.g. delta and alpha are what I'm actually solving for.)

Answer (score 1):

Well you can create a single variable vector `params = tf.Variable((2,), name="ab")` and then multiply with the identity matrix `tf.eye(2)`:

```
A = tf.matmul(tf.expand_dims(params,0), tf.eye(2))
```

Answer (score 1):

`tf.stack` increases the rank of the tensor (creating a new axis) and combines them in the new axis. If you want to combine tensors along an existing axis, you should use `tf.concat`.

```
a = tf.Variable((1,), name="a", dtype = tf.float64)
b = tf.Variable((1,), name="b", dtype = tf.float64)
const = tf.constant(0,dtype = tf.float64, shape = (1,))
A0 = tf.stack([a, const], axis=1)
A1 = tf.stack([const, b], axis=1)  # more clear than tf.transpose

A = tf.concat((A0, A1), axis=0)
```

A is now shape (2, 2).

To explain, each object is a rank-1 tensor with one element:

```
A = [1]
const = [0]
```

stacking gives:

```
tf.stack((A, const), axis=0) = [[1], [0]]  # 2x1 matrix
```

concatenating gives:

```
tf.concat((A, const), axis=0) = [1, 0]  # 2 vector
```